# pythonのseabornのインポートが反映されない

Tags: python3, matplotlib

Anacondaにseabornをインストールして以下のヒストグラムを書いてみたのですが，seabornの設定が反映されず，matplotlibのみで書いた図と見た目が変わりません．importエラーも起きていないのですが，どこが原因なのでしょうか？

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

追記：seabornのversionは0.8.0です

Comment: seaborn のバージョンを追記して下さいませんか？

Comment: @nekketsuuu 追記しました

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 解決策

プロットする前に [`sns.set()`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.set.html#seaborn.set) してください。

### 詳細

Seaborn バージョン 0.8.0 (2017年7月) から、`import seaborn` をしてもスタイル設定を seaborn のデフォルトで上書きしなくなりました (参考: [変更履歴](https://seaborn.pydata.org/whatsnew.html#v0-8-0-july-2017))。

このため、見た目を変えたければ [`set()`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.set.html#seaborn.set) を使って明示的に設定を変える必要があります。設定方法の詳細については[こちら](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/aesthetics.html)に公式チュートリアルがあり、API に関しては[こちら](http://seaborn.pydata.org/api.html#style-frontend)に一覧があります。

以下、私の環境での実行結果のスクリーンショットを添付します (環境: Python 3.6.0, matplotlib 2.0.0, seaborn 0.8.1, Jupyter Notebook 4.2.1)。

[image: Jupyter Notebook で実行した結果のスクリーンショットです。<code>sns.set</code> する前は matplotlib のデフォルト設定でグラフが描画されていますが、した後では seaborn のデフォルト設定で描画されています。]

Comment: @nekketsuuuさん，無事解決しました．ありがとうございました．